# Localstorage in my script seems not to be working

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have made some html/JavaScript codes like this:

```
<script>
if(window.localStorage!==undefined)
{
 }
else{ alert('Your browser is outdated!'); }
function myfunction1{
if(localStorage.getItem('permission')!="") { localStorage.setItem('permission', pressed);} 
function myfunction2{ document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('permission');}
</script>
<body onload="myfunction2()">
<p id="data">this paragraph shows storage data</p>
<button onclick="myfunction1()">press</button>
```

The first script is for checking whether the browser supports localstorage.
Second script (`myfunction1`) checks if there is any data called "permission". If there is none, then it will make one.
Third code (`myfunction2`) is for showing the localstorage data.
But none of these are working.  Maybe there is a simple problem on my code. But I can't fix it. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several syntax errors in your code:

1. You can check wether you web browser supports localStorage or not, just by doing `typeof(Storage) === "undefined"`, works for localStorage / sessionStorage.
2. Your functions need the correct syntax i.e. `function name() {handle}`
3. You didn't defined *pressed*, if a String is what you needed you forgot the double quotes`"pressed"` around it.

```html
<script>
if(typeof(Storage) === "undefined") {
  alert('Your browser is outdated!'); 
}

function myfunction1() {
  if(localStorage.getItem('permission')!="") 
  { localStorage.setItem('permission', 'pressed');} 
}

function myfunction2()  { 
  document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('permission');
}

</script>

<body onload="myfunction2()">
<p id="data">this paragraph shows storage data</p>
<button onclick="myfunction1()">press</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Your code have what I need. But there is a mistake in your code. if( typeof(Storage)!== "undefined") { alert('Your browser is outdated!'); } : this code is for making an alert, if    typeof(Storage)    is not undefined. Or if typeof(Storage) is defined. Change it to                   if(typeof(Storage) == "undefined") { alert('Your browser is outdated!'); }

Comment: My browser is alerting "Your browser is outdated" every time, when I open the page(which has the code from your answer). But localstorage setitem and getitem are working perfectly.

Comment: I'll choose your answer as correct. But requesting you to edit the answer, so that it may be helpful for other visitors.

Comment: @user8575948 Thanks for pointing that out, just edited it. Glad I could help.

Comment: your answer helped me, a lot

Comment: does it need 3=?

Comment: As for your question about conditions: == will convert the object and compare it, where === will only compare without doing any further conversion. You can refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons